# Simple SumIf in vba

Tags: vba, sumifs

I'm trying to do a sumifs function in vba using a prompted range. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub SumIfPositiveSelectedRange()
    Dim ThisRng As Range
    Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF((" & ThisRng.Address & "),">0")"
    End Sub
```

I get a Complile Error: Expected: end of statement. What am I missing?

Comment: remove the parenthesis around `" & ThisRng.Address & "`.  you are basicaly stating `=SumIf((A2:A500),">0")`

Comment: @Scott I tried this as you suggested and it still gives me a compile error. `Sub SumIfPositiveSelectedRange()
Dim ThisRng As Range
Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(" & ThisRng.Address & ",">0")""
End Sub`

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot the double quotes: `"=SUMif(" & ThisRng.Address & ","">0"")"`

Comment: Thanks for helping a noob out, that did it!

Answer (score 2):

As per my Comments.  When wanting the quotes to remain in the string one must use double quotes like thus:

```
Sub SumSelectedRange()
Dim ThisRng As Range
Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMif(" & ThisRng.Address & ","">0"")"
End Sub
```